# RecyclerView scroll to top button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add back to top button in my app. I use recyclerview for displaying items. I added button and when I click on it, view is going to top, but my goal is to show this button only if application is scrolled down or up, and my first item is not visible (I hope thats clear explanation). I tried with

```
LayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

and other methods for LayoutManager but without acceptable effects.

Comment: you tried adding the line of code in the onScrollListener? because if you scroll you should get a result from that.

Comment: @R.Zagórski its not duplicate, because I know how to add button and its working but I want to hide button when I dont need him

Comment: @R.Adang of course not :) Thanks for your advice I solved my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is showed below. I add OnScrollListener on my RecyclerView, and when view is scrolled I check if the first item is visible and I set visibility of my button.

```
MyRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int visibility = (MyLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() != 0) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        btn.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
});
```